# Google Chart Tools doesn't draw chart / failed drawing chart

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, charts

I want to draw a stock chart using Google Chart Tools. My self-written webservice returns a JSON-object with stock quotes. The JSON data is read by JQuery using $.getJSON(). Using console log I was able to check, that the data is read in in a correct way.

The JSON data looks like:

```
{ "share": [
{ "date": "2012-01-30", "open": 72.38, "close": 73.13 },
{ "date": "2012-01-23", "open": 77.71, "close": 72.80 },
{ "date": "2012-01-16", "open": 75.25, "close": 78.05 }
]}
```

For drawing I'm using the following code snippet:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var options = {
        width: 720, 
        height: 480,
        title: 'Chart'
    };

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');

    $.getJSON("StockReceiver.jsp",
        function(json) {
            $.each(json.share, function(i, item){
                console.log ([i, item.open]);
                data.addRow([i, item.open]);
                if ( i == 3 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

The problem I got is that the chart is not drawn! At first I've tried to draw the image with about 3.000 values. Since this doesn't worked I tried to draw one line using two number-values. (To point out if I did something wrong)

When I write

```
data.addRow([1, 20]);
data.addRow([2, 40]);
```

I see a line in the chart!

When I look into the $.each function call the loop causes the execution of

```
data.addRow([i, item.open]);
```

following values are set eg. (checked using console log)

```
data.addRow([0, 72.38]);
data.addRow([1, 77.71]);
data.addRow([2, 75.25]);
```

Why is the chart not drawn, when I try to execute data.addRow within the $.each function? I see a chart but without a line. I receive no error message at all with fireburg in firefox browser! In Internet Explorer it is also not working. Any ideas?

Suggested solution was:

```
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages : [ "corechart" ]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var options = {
        width : 720,
        height : 480,
        title : 'Chart'
    };

    $.getJSON("StockReceiver.jsp", function(json) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');

        $.each(json, function(i, item) {
            data.addRow([ new Date(item.date), item.open ]);
        });

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document
                .getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could it be "type" issue? Are 72.38 etc. numbers or strings?

Comment: As @Grilse suggested it was a problem using an ajax call. The chart was drawn (an empty one) and in parallel the StockReceiver tried to load the stock data. When the data was completly loaded I had to trigger the chart.draw function. I forgot this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with execution order. `$.getJSON()` issues an Ajax request. Ajax is asynchronous, meaning that processing continues in the meantime. What happens is the following.

1. A request for data is sent to "StockReceiver.jsp".
2. An empty chart is drawn.
3. The response from "StockReceiver.jsp" comes in, too late to be used in the chart.

The solution is to move the `chart.draw()` command into the Ajax callback `function(json) {...}`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work. It was a misunderstanding in using jquery in a correct way with asynchronous requests. Now it works and my stock chart is drawn :-)